# How to use animationFrame in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

The following code throws the exception `"type '([int]) => void' is not a subtype of type 'RequestAnimationFrameCallback' of 'callback'."`

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  window.animationFrame.then((time) => print("test"));
}
```

If I change `window.animationFrame.then` to `window.requestAnimationFrame`, everything works as expected. Am I misunderstanding how Dart futures work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage looks right.

Either you are running an older version that doesn't yet implement the behavior that is specified in the documentation or it is simply a bug. I would go ahead and file an issue on http://dartbug.com/new